# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos but values within limits

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to sympy and trying to define an equation and then numerically find the roots, but getting a "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos" error. Getting similar errors in sqrt and powers. Why does this happen?
My code is the following:

```
import sympy 

z = sympy.symbols('z')

beta_z = sympy.acos(1 - (2 * z   / 0.329))


test1 = sympy.lambdify(z, beta_z, modules=['numpy'])

solution1 = fsolve(test1, 2.54e-3)

print(solution1)
```

I get the following result:

```
[0.00254]

<string>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
```

Comment: Well, what is your understanding of how the arccosine function works? What input values are valid? Therefore, what possible `z` values are valid? Does it make sense that the `fsolve` algorithm would try `z` values outside that range?

Comment: Hi Karl,
Correct me if I'm wrong, but the arcos input values should be between -1 and 1, and the value must represent your quantity in radians. The above script is just part of a nested script where I need to find the root of a  complex equation. Since the exact solution does not exist, I have to convert the symbolic equation and try to find the root numerically. I'm pretty sure I must be doing something wrong since the same equations hold and can be solved in the other software.